# reputation system flawed

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As you probably all know, the reputation system is kind of flawed.
There are numerous posts and blogs complaining about this and analyzing in detail, so I'll skip it.

Just a few minutes ago, I saw a really stupid question on SO ...however, I wondered that the asker had a reputation in the many thousands. Then I opened its profile and saw it had 700+ very basic questions and merely 10 basic answers. Once again, it illustrated perfectly the problem with SO.

I'll boil it down to the following simple facts:

**the system favors asking very basic questions and discourages answering difficult ones**

- asking boosts reputation more easely than answering
- basic questions easily boost reputation, tricky/specific ones get almost no votes/views

As a result, SO is flooded with questions daily, dozens per minute. And only the very basic ones, that are googlable anyway, get a few views/answers. The more advanced ones get lost in the crowd forever.

**As such, here would be a drastic proposal to alter the reputation system to better reflect the level of helpfulness and expertise.**

1. Make asking questions *cost* reputation. Always. A bit like bounties, you would *have to* pay some of your reputation to ask. And new accounts would get something like 1 token to start with, so that they can't flood and have first to provide help before they can request help again.
2. By default, sort the questions by "reputation offered" amount. So that the big contributors/experts get more exposure when sometimes requiring help.
3. Distribute the "reputation offered" among the repliers. Of course, in order to increase the reputation points in the "economy", you'd have to, for example, reward twice the reputation points that the asker "paid".

So, what do you think?

Comment: For *"As you probably all know"*, read *"some people claim"*.

Comment: Oh well, I'll just quit SO too then, it's probably not the right site for me. At the very beginning, long long ago, it was a site to be helpful for developers, now it's a site for noobs too lazy to google it. But if you're happy with it, have fun.

Comment: @arnaud you could just *not answer simple questions*, and seek out the *"more advanced ones"*. Be the change you want to see in the world!

Comment: Just as a comment, I never said reputation was a measurement for anything. It was a proposal to use it as a sort of currency.

Comment: If you feel that SO isn't the right site for you simply because of how reputation is awarded, then it sounds like you're taking reputation too seriously. That should never be the primary reason for contributing. If you answer a difficult question which will help the asker and multiple future readers, does it really matter whether or not a particular number increases?

Comment: analizing... :/

Comment: > member for 5 years > 2140 rep > mfw

Comment: @jon skeet it's not about reputation per se. It's that there are dozens of questions flooding per minute, most of them unanswered with a couple of views at most. If you have a non-trivial question, there are high chances it'll just go under the radar. So, yeah, I'd prefer to introduce a cost to asking, so that tougher questions also have a chance to get answered. And also a reward for spending time on more difficult questions. Isn't it ok to make the system more fair?

Comment: On the surface, you are contemplating quitting SO because questions you perceive as being too simple etc get more rep (= fake internet points) than those you consider more complex and 'worthy'... define what is 'too simple', or as you put it 'too basic' - where is the dividing line between basic and 'acceptable'?  You do realise that this division will be different for everyone, hence very subjective.  I sincerely hope this kind of proposal ***never*** gets implemented.

Comment: @arnaud: In my experience, a good question rarely goes ignored, however non-trivial it is. And the primary "reward" for spending time on SO is the recognition of making the world a better place. Also note that spending time on easy topics - where actually it can be harder to give a really good answer, as you may need to rethink how to express concepts to meet the expected experience level - can help more people in the long run. I wouldn't want to discourage that.

Answer (score 13):

The flaw here is the assumption that reputation means `how smart a person is` or `how good a person is in a technology`.  It doesn't mean any of those things, and it doesn't attempt to measure any of those things.

What it does: it measures *how involved in the community you are*, and *how other people view your contributions*.  The fact that someone who has a lot of fairly basic questions has a high reputation is unsurprising, and is a *good* thing: it means they are highly involved in the community, and they can ask good (or at least, good enough) questions.

That's good for us: we have to have a lot of fairly basic questions to keep StackOverflow (and other SE sites) running.  Esoteric, difficult answers are good to have, but they don't really get us much: maybe three people ever benefit from the answer, well, that's good, but it's only helping three people.  Answers - and questions - that help a few hundred people will by their nature be more basic, but they're still very useful, because they're helping *a few hundred people*.

Comment: Just as a comment, I never said reputation was a measurement for anything. It was a proposal to use it as a sort of currency.

Answer (score 4):

I dispute the claim that "asking boosts reputation more easely than answering". I just flat out do not agree with that. I also do not believe that the reputation system is flawed.

However, the idea of requiring reputation to ask a question would be an interesting addition to rate limiting. I wonder how many 1 rep users ask more than 1 question while at 1 reputation and what percent of those questions asked (aside from the first) were closed.

If it were a significant portion, perhaps adding a *very small* reputation requirement for asking could be an interesting idea. Perhaps something like 1 reputation to ask, aside from the first question you ask which requires no reputation. This would also be inline with the current outlook that asking questions should be seen as a commodity.

Comment: I think the rate limiting you're talking about is already (sort of) there.  If I wanted to I could ask a few dozen questions pretty easily.  A new user can't.

Comment: @Joe - Yes, perhaps it was not worded perfectly, but the rate limiting I was referring to is the system already in place.